# PDF header appending with NULNULNULNUL%PDF-1.6

Tags: pdf

In our Application we have functionality to view / download PDF files
Below is the code used for download and display in browser

```
> while ((readLength = bufInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
outStream.write(buffer, 0, readLength);
}
}
```

recently we observed like getting popup like "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired."

when we checked the contents of good and bad pdf

---

### good.pdf

starts with "%PDF-1.6" 
ends with "%%EOF"

---

### bad.pdf

starts with "NULNULNULNUL%PDF-1.6"

### ends with "506053"

When we checked with Original PDF , which was streamed have proper header

If we buffer and write, how these character added in Header???

> 03 jun 2018

Have you checked the data from your bufInputStream?
we need to print the data? or how to check data?
Have you checked what happens to data written to your outStream?
we need to print the data? or how to check data?

I googled and got some information as below
1.if your observe the bad pdf ends with,%%EOF is missing. May be this due to outstream.write is not happening in last loop(please correct me)
2.Recently host which made some graphics changes in PDF contents and after that this issue started
3.old pdf's are working fine without any issue , only issue with new pdf's
4.we are serving this funtionailty for various clients and only this new pdf's are getting issue (with win10+IE11) + (win7+IE11)
4.Any Browse setting or Acrobat plugin will resolve this issue?
5.What could be reason on streaming these character added / deleted?

> 4 jun 2018

seems like %%EOF at end missing is the root cause for the issue. We got bad / corrupted file from application and manually added %%EOF at the end resolved the issue. now couple of questions

- how this is worked before?

  - when NUL NUL header added , why %%EOF Not appended to streamed data?
  - is there any setting we can add %%EOF by automatically to streamed data?
  - we need to do a code change for this?
  - there is any Acrobat or webspehere or browser setting to resolve this issue?

> 11 Jun

We done code change to add %%EOF in missed PDF files(temp work around).
We try to print what is coming through Network..
We saw NULNUL is coming , but HOST saying they are not sending..
we have Load Balancers , other components in network channel
We got old PDF files from cacheServer and  saw like these characters from long time
Issue started from PDF1.6 version.

Comment: The `while` loop looks ok.

Comment: In other words: I doubt your error is caused by that loop. Have you checked the data from your `bufInputStream`? And have you checked what happens to data written to your `outStream`?

Comment: Concerning your responses in your edit: you can check the data you receive from `bufInputStream` by writing it not only to `outStream` but in parallel also to some file stream and inspect that file afterwards. As mentioned above, your copying loop as such is ok, so you can trust the result in that file. To check what happens to data written to your `outStream` save the file the client receives and compare. And, of course, have a look at the code processing the data written up that stream.

Comment: On **1**: *"May be this due to outstream.write is not happening in last loop"* - unless there is some exception, that `write` is called. Thus, either your input stream already misses the end or the further processing by your output drops it or adds much dross afterwards. On **2** and **3**: if the error only occurs for changed inputs and not for the original inputs, you should really review the files created with the change. And you should review how the `bufInputStream` is created.

Comment: On **4**: *"only this new pdf's are getting issue (with win10+IE11) + (win7+IE11)"* - do they only have the issue if viewed using IE? Or do you only test with IE? On your other **4**: first try to find the cause before playing around with settings. On **5**: some bug somewhere.

Comment: After your next edit... have you checked the input of your loop? Have you checked what happens to the output?

Comment: few things i found as root cause   <1> Our code is only reading upto readLength passed  <2>If some extra characters added by any of the network components , which result in reading EOF  <3>Want to know who is adding NULNULNULNUL%PDF-1.6 in between HOST and our application

Comment: *"Want to know who is adding NULNULNULNUL%PDF-1.6 in between HOST and our application "* - A good question indeed...